# What does this mean : to be so (past tense verb)?

Tags: expressions

What does it mean when we use "so" with a verb, like we say "he is so gone", or "he is so done with something"?

It sounds like emphasizing on something but I don't see how "being gone" could be emphasized?

Comment: @MetaEd off-topic, hah? I don't see how you Not  put that subject in English category?!

Comment: @jimm101 I don't see why people in here like that "off-topic" button a lot!

Comment: There is a specific reason given. Posts that do not include results of your prior research will be closed.

Comment: @parvin This site is different than a regular message board. It's for authoritative, definitive answers to questions on a specific topic. Close votes aren't final. Many questions can become on-topic by modifying  their form. In your case, you haven't posted any research. The site isn't appropriate for things you can simply google.

Answer (score 1):

The 'so' as in "he is so good" is mainly for emphasis, and might also indicate that there is an explanation of just how good he is, i.e. "he is so good, that [..]".

See also the usage notes here: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/so#Adverb

> The difference between so and very in implied-extent usage is that *very* is more descriptive or matter-of-fact, while *so* indicates more emotional involvement. For example, *she is very clever* is a simple statement of opinion; *she is so clever* suggests admiration.

Edit: you can also find the following quotes:

> I so want to see the Queen when she visits our town!

and

> That is so not true!

which you might find interesting..

Comment: Of course, she could also be *so very clever*. ;)

Comment: @JasonBassford yes, that's just, so very true

Comment: thanks for answering but I EXACTLY WROTE "Past tense verb" not adjective.

Comment: I checked the link and found something cool:
"I so want to see the Queen when she visits our town!"
and "That is so not true!"__
please post these in your answer so that I can choose it as an answer, they say it's off-topic and it's not, I don't want my post being deleted. thank you.

Comment: @parvin I added those quotes to the answer : -)

Comment: @parvin You did not actually write “past tense verb”; you just wrote “a verb”. But then your examples don’t use past tense verbs either, but adjectives. Using a past tense verb in this context would actually be quite ungrammatical; “he is so went” is not a possible construction in English.

Comment: I did write past tense verb, on the title.

Comment: ok, imagine all I wrote was adjective, what does so mean in "he is **so** me" , is "me" adjective?! it's not, it's just some grammatically wrong expression showing emphasis.